# Unexpected behavior in Chrome extension and "localStorage"-property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a fairly simple Chrome extension: When "active", it should copy some source code whenever the content.js is sending the correct data:

*background.js*

```
...
// when active, listen for content.js and copy content into clipboard
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.from === "content" && active === true) {
            copyTextToClipboard(request.message)
        }
});
```

Setting the extension "active" is done by clicking the extension icon in the Chrome tab:

*background.js*

```
...
// turn the logo color and set activity status upon clicking the extension logo in the tab

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    active = !active;
    localStorage.setItem("active_stored", active);
    if (active) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon_yellow.png"})
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon_grey.png"})
    }
});
...
```

It is almost running as expected (i.e. clicking the icon sets `active=true` or `false`, indicated by the extension logo changing accordingly).
However, I want to save the activity status using `localStorage`, so that it remains intact even after shutting down Chrome.

So I added the following code:

*background.js*:

```
...
// turn the logo color and set activity status upon starting up Chrome browser
let active = localStorage.getItem("active_stored");
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
    if (active) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon_yellow.png"})
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon_grey.png"})
    }
});
...
```

However, when restarting Chrome, regardless of the state I left `active` in, the "active" logo is being displayed and the variable is set to `true` (which I find weird, but I could live with), but the source code is not being copied! Clicking the icon twice, i.e. deactivating and activating, will result in the expected behavior!

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong with this?

P.S.: I originally tried this with `chrome.storage.set` and `chrome.storage.get`, but the using the callback function really confused me. After having read multiple articles and other questions, I feel like this might be necessary in order to solve this problem. Please let me if a) it indeed is the only way to get this done and b) how to properly integrate this functionality.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the values in `localStorage` are saved as `string` which means that both the `"true"` and `"false"` strings are **truthy** values.

To convert the values from `localStorage` to `boolean`, use something like this:

```
let active = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("active_stored"));
```